# sunspot_solr error on heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, solr, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

I'm using `'sunspot_rails', '~> 2.0.0.pre.120415'` for Solr search in my rails app and deploy it on heroku (two separate application).
It's working fine on one application but throw error on other.

I have checked the heroku environment and found that -
one app is on cedar stack and ruby version is 1.9.2p290. (Working fine)
other one is on bamboo stack and ruby version is 1.9.2p180 (throw error)

So, Is this the ruby version problem or heroku stack problem ?
Ruby version on development environment is 1.9.2p290.

**Error**

```
$ heroku run rake sunspot:reindex
Running rake sunspot:reindex attached to terminal... up, run.8567
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant Sunspot::Adapters::Registry::Forwardable
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sunspot-2.0.0.pre.120925/lib/sunspot/adapters.rb:310:in `<class:Registry>'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sunspot-2.0.0.pre.120925/lib/sunspot/adapters.rb:309:in `<module:Adapters>'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sunspot-2.0.0.pre.120925/lib/sunspot/adapters.rb:34:in `<module:Sunspot>'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sunspot-2.0.0.pre.120925/lib/sunspot/adapters.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sunspot-2.0.0.pre.120925/lib/sunspot.rb:18:in `block in <top (required)>'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sunspot-2.0.0.pre.120925/lib/sunspot.rb:15:in `each'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sunspot-2.0.0.pre.120925/lib/sunspot.rb:15:in `<top (required)>'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sunspot_rails-2.0.0.pre.120925/lib/sunspot/rails.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sunspot_rails-2.0.0.pre.120925/lib/sunspot_rails.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
/app/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/app/Rakefile:4:in `require'
/app/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: Not enough information. How about showing us the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be even more clear, at the top of adapters.rb (sunspot/lib/sunspot/adapters.rb), add the following line:

```
 require 'forwardable'


 module Sunspot
   #
   # Sunspot works by saving references to the primary key (or natural ID) of
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution.

Actually it's a environment problem on heroku.On local system the ruby version is ruby 1.9.2p290 and on heroku is ruby 1.9.2p180. Ruby 1.9.2p180 doesn't include 'Forwardable' module. So I just need to include 'Forwardable' module in my application.

Comment: can you tell us where exactly you included what module exactly. Thx

Comment: In application.rb, I add this require 'forwardable'